# Loopback: model.settings.validateUpsert was overriden to false

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopback

I have a loopback app with MongoDB as below, however my question is about a message on my terminal (not an error) so my terminal would look like this:

```
dishes settings.validateUpsert was overriden to false
Comments settings.validateUpsert was overriden to false
Web server listening at: http://localhost:3000
Browse your REST API at http://localhost:3000/explorer
```

The path to my app folder....> node .

As you can see that the server runs without an error. What is the meaning of that message? I managed to avoid it by setting TimeStamp to false like this:

```
"mixins": {
    "TimeStamp": true // => change this to  false.
  }
```

but I'm not convinced with this solution.

Here are my models:

dish.json:

```
    {
  "name": "dishes",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "description": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "category": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "image": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "label": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true,
      "default": "''"
    },
    "price": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true,
      "default": "0"
    }
  },
  "mixins": {
    "TimeStamp": true
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "comments": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Comments",
      "foreignKey": ""
    },
    "customers": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Customer",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  },
  "acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "READ",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$authenticated",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "EXECUTE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "admin",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "create"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "WRITE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "admin",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    }
  ],
  "methods": {}
}
```

comments.json:

```
    {
  "name": "Comments",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "Rating": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true,
      "default": 5
    },
    "comment": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "mixins": {
    "TimeStamp": true
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "dishes": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "dishes",
      "foreignKey": ""
    },
    "customer": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Customer",
      "foreignKey": "customerId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "DENY"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "READ",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$authenticated",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "EXECUTE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$authenticated",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "create"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "WRITE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    }
  ],
  "methods": {}
}
```

customer.json:

```
    {
  "name": "Customer",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {},
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "comments": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Comments",
      "foreignKey": "customerId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "DENY"
    }
  ],
  "methods": {}
}
```

and script.js:

```
    module.exports = function(app) {
var MongoDB = app.dataSources.MongoDB;

MongoDB.automigrate('Customer', function(err) {
   if (err) throw (err);
   var Customer = app.models.Customer;

   Customer.create([
    {username: 'Admin', email: 'admin@admin.com', password: 'abcdef'},
    {username: 'muppala', email: 'muppala@ust.hk', password: 'abcdef'}
  ], function(err, users) {
        if (err) throw (err);
        var Role = app.models.Role;
        var RoleMapping = app.models.RoleMapping;

        Role.find({ name: 'admin' }, function(err, results) {
            if (err) { throw err; }

            if (results.length < 1) {
                // now we know the DB doesn't have it already, so do the Role creation...
                //create the admin role
                Role.create({
                  name: 'admin'
                }, function(err, role) {
                  if (err) throw (err);
                   //make admin
                  role.principals.create({
                    principalType: RoleMapping.USER,
                    principalId: users[0].id
                  }, function(err, principal) {
                    if (err) throw (err);
                  });
                });
            }
        });
  });
});

};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a requirement for `loopback-ds-timestamp-mixin`.

See https://github.com/clarkbw/loopback-ds-timestamp-mixin/blob/master/es6/time-stamp.js#L25.

If `validateUpsert` were `true`, the mixin shows a warn:

> "Upserts for ModelName will fail when validation is turned on and time stamps are required"

### UPDATE

To hide this warns, set the TimeStamp mixin like this:

```
...
"mixins": {
    "TimeStamp": {
      "required" : false,
      "validateUpsert": true,
      "silenceWarnings": false
    }
},
...
```

Comment: Will it change any behavior? will it create timestamp(createdAt,updatedAt) even if it has `"required" : false`?